# ready-made Topics in using LDA to categorize documents?

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing, gensim

I'm using LDA to categorize small documents, about 4-5 lines.

I'm categorizing them into topics such as Technology, Politics, Art, Music etc etc

I'm using wikipedia to download articles in each category (Technology, Politics, Art etc etc) and training LDA for each category

Wikipedia is huge (about 8GB compressed), and computations take hours! and uses a huge space in my hard drive

Is there any toolkit that already provides "ready-made" generic topics which i can directly use for categorization?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few online API's that categorize text into a predefined set of topics. For example,  https://www.textrazor.com/demo identifies topics such as Business, Law, and Politics. You can also take a look at [MeaningCloud](https://www.meaningcloud.com/demos/media-analysis/) or [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/demo/alchemylanguage). Most of these services are paid, but do have a free tier that may be sufficient, depending on your needs.